# Why does react hook throw the act error when used with fetch api?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I keep getting `Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).` in my test suite whenever I make an API request and update the state.

I'm making use of react-testing-library. I also tried using ReactDOM test utils, got the same result. One other thing I tried was wrapping the container in `act`, still got the same result.

Please note that: My App works and my test passes. I just need to know what I was doing wrong or if it's a bug in the react-dom package that's making that error show up. And it's bad to mock the console error and mute it.

```
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');

it('should clear select content item', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ results: data }));

    const { container } = render(<App />);

    const content = container.querySelector('.content');

    await wait();

    expect(content.querySelectorAll('.content--item').length).toBe(2);
});
```

Here's the hook implementation:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState('');

const fetchInitData = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(API_URL);
        const data = await res.json();

        if (data.fault) {
            setError('Rate limit Exceeded');
        } else {
            setData(data.results);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        setError(e.message);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchInitData();
}, [isEqual(data)]);
```

Comment: Is this all within a function?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Lemme add that it's working and my test passes. It only issue is the annoying errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a known problem, check this issue in Github https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/281

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who stumbles upon this more than a year later as I did, the issue Giorgio mentions has since been resolved, and `wait` has since been replaced with `waitFor`, as documented here:

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

That being the case, I believe the solution to the warning now should be something like this:

```js
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
// ...

it('should clear select content item', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ results: data }));

    const { container } = render(<App />);

    const content = container.querySelector('.content');

    await waitFor(() =>
        expect(content.querySelectorAll('.content--item').length).toBe(2);
    );
});
```

In my case, I had an `App` component loading data asynchronously in a `useEffect` hook, and so I was getting this warning on every single test, using `beforeEach` to render `App`. This was the specific solution for my case:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await waitFor(() => render(<App />));
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the `act()` warning you need to make sure your promises resolve synchronously. You can read [here](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples#async--await) how to do this.

Summary:

> The solution for this is a bit involved:
>
> - we polyfill Promise globally with an implementation that can resolve
>     promises 'immediately', such as promise
> - transpile your javascript with a custom babel setup like the one in this repo
> - use jest.runAllTimers(); this will also now flush the promise task queue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and gave up using wait and async instead used jest faketimers and so on, so your code should be something like this.

```js
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');

it('should clear select content item', /*async */ () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ results: data }));

    const { container } = render(<App />);

    const content = container.querySelector('.content');

    // await wait();
    act(() => {
      jest.runAllTimers();
    });

    expect(content.querySelectorAll('.content--item').length).toBe(2);
});
```